# Fertilization of the human egg- where does our centrosome come from?

Tags: genetics, cell-biology, embryology, meiosis, gamete

Is there a centrosome in a human egg cell? Is the reason why the egg cell remains paused before meiosis 2 because there isn't a centrosome, and it only divides when the sperm fertilizes it thus it can have a centrosome? If this is so, then how did oogenesis happen? ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the first part of your question. **The sperm actually introduces two centrosomes. The centrosome then nucleates the new microtubule assembly to form the sperm aster — a step essential for successful fertilization.** You can visit these sites [Simerly, et al](https://www.nature.com/articles/nm0195-47) as well as [Paweltz, et al](https://europepmc.org/abstract/med/3691547)

Comment: Could you provide a more recent reference? (The ones you provided are from 1995 and 1987). I ask because [From Zero to Many: Control of Centriole Number in Development and Disease](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1600-0854.2009.00905.x) (2009) says: "Notably, oocytes and spermatozoa lose parts of the centrosome in a complementary manner. Centrioles, but not centrosome proteins, are lost in the oocyte. On the other hand, in sperm, the PCM material is lost, but not the centriole/basal body, which is necessary for flagella formation.  ...

Comment: ...  Fertilization brings together the basal body from the sperm, which becomes a centriole within the zygote, and the PCM from the egg."